# XML and XSD validation failed using restriction

Tags: xml, xsd, restriction

After Using the Restriction validation gives error **Unknown Node: Restriction** 
I am not able to find the error. Can anybody help me out in XSD. 
this is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DataChannelconfig>
        <DataTypeVersion>1</DataTypeVersion>
        <FileformatVersion>0</FileformatVersion>
        <DataChannel>
            <Name>Supply Pump Flow Speed</Name>
            <Datatype>Numeric</Datatype>
            <Tag>Supply_Pump_Flow_Speed</Tag>
            <Graph>
                <Enable>0</Enable>
                <AxisNo>0</AxisNo>
                <Colour>255.0.225</Colour>
            </Graph>
            <Table>
                <Enable>1</Enable>
                <Table-ID>0</Table-ID>
                <Table-Row>9</Table-Row>
                <Unit>ml/min</Unit>
            </Table>
    </DataChannel>
</DataChannelconfig>
```

This is My XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="DataChannelconfig">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="DataTypeVersion" type="xs:byte"/>
    <xs:element name="FileformatVersion" type="xs:byte" />
    <xs:element name="DataChannel" type="xs:string">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Name"> 
         <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/
          </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute> 
       <xs:element name="Datatype" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Datatype"> 
         <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
       <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Datatype"> 
         <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
       <xs:element name="Graph">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Enable"/>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
           </xs:restriction>
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="AxisNo"/>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
           </xs:restriction>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Colour"/>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}"/>
           </xs:restriction>
          </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="Table">
         <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Enable"/>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
             <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
             <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
            </xs:restriction>
            <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="Table-ID"/>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
              <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
              <xs:maxInclusive value="3"/>
             </xs:restriction>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Table-Row"/>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
              <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
              <xs:maxInclusive value="14"/>
             </xs:restriction>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Unit"/>
             <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/>
             </xs:restriction>
          </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What is wrong in my XSD file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio trying to open your schema I got

> Failed to load schema.
>
> Reason : 
>   The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attribute' element is not supported in this contex

The problems are

1. You have declared both Elements and Attributes with the same name in the sequence.  Attributes should reside outside of (after) the sequence. But your sample does not have any attributes, so I have removed them.
2. You have forgotten the closing > on this line

   `<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/`
3. The element Graph is missing a closing tag
4. The elements, Enable, AxisNo & Colour etc. are self terminated, they need to be terminated after the restriction which needs to be wrapped by a type nodes rather than the type declared on the element.

This is what is should look like.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="DataChannelconfig">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="DataTypeVersion" type="xs:byte"/>
        <xs:element name="FileformatVersion" type="xs:byte" />
        <xs:element name="DataChannel">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Datatype">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Graph">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Enable">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                        <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="AxisNo">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                        <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Colour">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Table">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="Enable">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                            <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element  name="Table-ID">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                            <xs:maxInclusive value="3"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="Table-Row">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:byte">
                            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                            <xs:maxInclusive value="14"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:element>
                      <xs:element name="Unit">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_.'!@#$%^*()]{20}"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Using the above schema against your sample gives the following output

```
The 'Name' element is invalid - The value 'Supply Pump Flow Speed' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed.
The 'Datatype' element is invalid - The value 'Numeric' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed.
The 'Colour' element is invalid - The value '255.0.225' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed.
The 'Table-ID' element is invalid - The value '0' is invalid according to its datatype 'Byte' - The MinInclusive constraint failed.
The 'Unit' element is invalid - The value 'ml/min' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Pattern constraint failed.
```

Comment: Can anybody suggest me how can I give following restriction pattern 
1) I want to use Restriction with alphanumeric values _[a-zA-Z0-9.'!@#$%^*()]_ . Also **stringlength** of _20_ characters. But I cant do that using this XSD schema.
2) For restriction of **Colour** Element, I want to validate my xml with RGB colour format i.e I want to validate _255.0.255_ format.

Comment: 1) Yes you can have a stringlength of 20, that is what you have. But what you have done it has to be exactly 20, no more no less, if you want it less you need to have something like {0,20}.  2) Same issue with this, you have told it you want each one to be exactly 3 digits long

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really means a Lot. Another help. I want to use a space in Name element and Special character. Can you direct me for that ?

Comment: @YagnikPatel Please post that as a new question.

Comment: I got the solution for my all requirement. I am posting my solved example for future usage for someone like me.                                      '<xs:element name="Name">
                 <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([^\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9_. '!@#$%^*()_+={}|/:;,>?/`~]){0,20}"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>'    :) thanks a Lot @ Dijkgraaf